# how to add multiline comment with /* */ using shortcut keys in netbeans IDE 8.3

Tags: netbeans, editor, shortcut

Looking for the shortcut key to add multiline(/* */) comments.

shortcut : "Ctr+/" used to add the comment but its comes with "//"
like this ..

```
//line1
//line2
//line3
```

I want the comments like below one , using shortcuts key..

```
/*     line 1
       line 2
       line 3
    */
```

Comment: There is no release 8.3 of NetBeans, and there never will be. The current release is 8.2 and the next release will be 9, so you should correct the title of your question. (Did you mean8.2?)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Netbeans 8.2. **For multiline comments**

---

just type `/*` **OR** `/**` and then press **Enter**.

---

Hopefully, this will work.

---

When you use `/**` to add a comment for an existing method it will generate a skeleton Javadoc for that method.

[image: default comment structure]

but as I know Netbeans 8.3 is not released and never will be. Version 9 will be released instead. You might use version 8.2 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut for a multi-line comment in NetBeans, presumably because there is no need for one; if you simply type **/*** and press **Enter** then NetBeans will automatically insert a blank line, followed by ***/** on the next line, and then position the cursor on the blank line:

`/*
{cursor is set here}
*/`

(Somewhat related, and slightly more impressive, you can also type **/**** and press **Enter** on the line before a method and NetBeans will generate a skeleton Javadoc for that method.)

Comment: Yes, I search lot but not found any shortcut key for this.